# How do I create a strategy with pine script to buy and sell based on barcolor changes from an indicator I created?

Tags: pine-script

I created an indicator that changes the color of the bar when a few parameters are met. When the barcolor closes yellow I want to look to sell on the next bar. When the barcolor closes white I want to look to buy on the next candle. I have tried what I can find but nothing seems to directly relate to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Use the parameters that you used to set the color to create the buy/sell signals. Unless you provide better details no one will be able to help you more than this. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.